# Contar las veces que uso un macro en Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

mi problema es, tengo un macro abre un UserForm que da dos opciones una para pegar texto y otra para pegar imagenes. Mi problema surge cuando quiero crear otra macro, un contador que muestre en un Msgbox cuantas veces use cada uno o por lo menos cuantas veces ejecute el primer macro (el que abria el userform), la verdad siempre e batallado con los contadores por lo que agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Debes proveer un [mcve] para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes declarar una variable global entera que lleve la cuenta.

Para esto, simplemente declara la variable fuera de la función:

```
Public contador As Integer

Private Sub Ejemplo1_Click()
    contador = contador + 1
    MsgBox ("Se ha presionado " & contador & " veces")
End Sub
```

[image: gif]

En tu macro debería quedar algo así:

```
Public contador As Integer

Sub TuMacro()
contador = contador + 1   ' suma 1 al contador

' Realizas más acciones del macro...

End Sub
```